# How can I make a checkbox hierarchy tree In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree

#### What I have

I have a checkbox tree component that can select multiple elements, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBxHv.png).

For this I only need two components (in this approach) the `TreeNode` and the `Node` component, here you have the code for this two components:

**TreeNode component**

```js
const TreeNode = ({
  data = [],
  selectedNodeId,
  setSelectedNodeId,
}: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((singleNode: any) => (
        <Node
          key={singleNode.id}
          node={singleNode}
          selectedNodeId={selectedNodeId}
          setSelectedNodeId={setSelectedNodeId}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Node component**

```js
const Node = ({
  node,
  selectedNodeId,
  setSelectedNodeId,
}: any) => {
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const hasChildren = !!node.children.length;
  const isSelected = selectedNodeId === node.id;

  return (
    <div
      onClick={(event) => {
        setSelectedNodeId(node.id);
        event.stopPropagation();
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <div>
          {hasChildren && (
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={["fas", "angle-right"]}
              className={`node__icon ${visibility ? "active" : ""}`}
              onClick={(event) => {
                setVisibility(!visibility);
                event.stopPropagation();
              }}
            />
          )}
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <div>{node.name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {hasChildren && visibility && (
          <TreeNode
            data={node.children}
            selectedNodeId={selectedNodeId}
            setSelectedNodeId={setSelectedNodeId}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And also a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-hierarchy-5hhsdq?file=/src/App.tsx).

#### What I need

I need some strategy or advice to check or uncheck the parent node when all the children are selected or unselected, and this must be recursive, [for example, here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS49W.png) if I check "Test 4" and "Test 5", "Test 3" must be checked and "Test" must be "middle-check".

Its ok if you don't have any code but have some advice or suggestion :)

Thank you for your time!